# How to redirect one of several subdomains to localhost port on Plesk?

Tags: apache2, subdomain, port, plesk

I have a vps(Plesk, ubuntu) with one ip. I create a domain.com on the IP and several subdomains like jenkins.domain.com and blog.domain.com .
Now i wanted to redirect jenkins.domain.com to port 1122 and use this for [example](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server). But unfortunately all subdomains redirect then to domain.com:1122. What i want at the End is :

**jenkins.domain.com** redirect to **domain.com:1122** without changing the url.

**roundcube.domain.com** redirect to **domain.com:8844** without changing the url.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide config with what you actually done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it like just adding this config to the vhost.conf my subdomain(i.e jenkins) or into **web server settings** in Plesk.

```
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:1122/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:1122/
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy http://localhost:1122/*>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: still works in plesk onyx, just don't forget activating apache Webserver module proxy_http

Answer (score 0):

If all subdomains redirect it means that you have set wildcard virtual host. You have to create or modify two virtual host for every subdomain.